# Moving cursor to end

Tags: function-keys, lenovo-laptop

I have always been used to pressing 'End' to move the cursor to the end of a sentence.

I have just got a new Lenovo laptop with Windows 7. Now I have to press Fn+End to do the same.

Why? Any way to change it?

Comment: Why? Should be obvious; it's because the laptop lacks a stand-alone End key. Generally Fn+PgDn = End, so what do you want to do? Make End the default and press Fn+End to activate PgDn instead? Or remap End to some other key?

Comment: Just want to go back...i.e. Press 'End' and that should take me to the end of a sentence...

Comment: So which key is combined with End? Is it PgDn? Also, which Lenovo model is this? There might be a way to lock Fn on or off by default perhaps, as is the case with some laptops.

Comment: According to his answer below it's a Lenovo X240. End and Insert share the same key.

Answer (score 1):

You can use software like AutoHotKey to remap a key. You can designate a new key for "End". Or, suppose "End" is mapped to "Insert", you can map "Insert" to some lessor used key and map "End" to "End".

http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm

There are other options.

http://vlaurie.com/computers2/Articles/remap-keyboard.htm

I would try the "The Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator" because it is made by Microsoft.

Obviously, you must be running Windows for above solutions to work.